# Convert Mysql date with JavaScript to euro format

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to convert a MySQL date to euro date with JavaScript. but no success. My code is:

```
var t = "2014-03-29 13:12:01".split(/[- :]/);

// Apply each element to the Date function
var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);

alert(d);
```

I get a result of something like this: `Sat Mar 29 2014 23:24:28`

Is there a way to set it to something like `31.12.2014` with JavaScript? I can't use a server side language such as PHP.

Comment: How could you possibly get the 31st of December from that date? o.O

Comment: well you can change the date format at the time of selection in mysql using mysql `date_format()`

Comment: Also, what's wrong with simply using `new Date('2014-03-29 13:12:01')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) comes to rescue if you don’t care about options for Safari users.

```
var t = new Date("2014-03-29 13:12:01");
t.toLocaleString('fr');
// ⇒ "29/3/2014 13:12:01"
t.toLocaleString('ru');
// ⇒ "29.3.2014 13:12:01"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try It :

var t = "2014-03-29 13:12:01".split(/[- :]/);    

// Apply each element to the Date function    
var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);    

 var curr_date = d.getDate(t);    
var curr_month = d.getMonth(t) + 1; //Months are zero based    
var curr_year = d.getFullYear(t);    
var f = curr_date + "." + curr_month + "." + curr_year;    
alert(f);    

alert(d);
```